# Link 1 entity with many others kind of entities

Tags: symfony

Let say I have a Company for which I manage `Employees, Cars, Contracts, Buildings, Sites, Products,` etc. As you can guess, these are quite independant things, so no *inheritance* is possible.

For each of these elements (i.e. *Entities*), I want to be able to attach one or several  `Document`s (click on a button, form opens, select one/several `Document` or upload a new one).

**Linking `Document` to one kind of entity is not a problem, my problem is that there are many kinds of entities**. How should I manage that? I have 2 ideas which have their own problems...:

1. Create a ManyToMany relationship between Document and Employee, another between Document and Car, etc.

   - **Problem**: I have to duplicate the Controller code to attach Document, duplicate the forms, etc.
2. Create a single join table containing the Document's ID, the related entity's ID and the related entity's class name.

   - **Problem**: it doesn't look really clean to me, I didn't really dig in this way but I feel I'll have a lot of "entity mapping" problems.

Any suggestion?

---

**[EDIT]**

In fact I have to do the same for `Event` as well: I need to link some `Events` to some `Employees` and/or to some `Cars`, etc. And in my real case, I have more than 10 Entities to be linked to `Event` and/or `Document`, which means duplicating more tha 20 times the code if I go with the solution 1!

Comment: What about a unidirectional ManyToMany? Does the document care about which entities it's linked to in your domain?

Comment: Unidirectional is OK, but the problem remains: even like this I'll have to duplicate forms/treatements or make a weird common form/treatment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I managed to solve my problem, following @Rpg600 idea about Mapped Superclasses.

This is probably not the best and cleanest solution ever, I'm not really proud of it but it does the job and it is still better than my first ideas.

I create a `BaseEntity` which is my a mapped superclass (`Employee`, `Car`, etc. Entities have to extend this Class):

```
/**
 * BaseEntity
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyProject\MediaBundle\Entity\Folder")
     */
    private $folder;


    /**
     * Set folder
     * @param \Webobs\MediaBundle\Entity\Folder $folder
     * @return BaseEntity
     */
    public function setFolder(\Webobs\MediaBundle\Entity\Folder $folder = null){
        $this->folder = $folder;        
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get folder
     * @return \Webobs\MediaBundle\Entity\Folder
     */
    public function getFolder(){
        return $this->folder;
    }        
}
```

As it is not possible to have a Many-to-Many relationship in a superclass, I use a `Folder` which will contain one or several `Document`. This is the dirty part of the solution ; the `folder` table basically contain only one field which is the id...

```
class Folder
{
    private $id;

    /**
     * Note : Proprietary side
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyProject\MediaBundle\Entity\Document", inversedBy="folders", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_in_folder")
     */
    private $documents;
    // setters and getters
```

Then I create a helper class (which is declared as a service) to manage the link between any `Entity` and the `Document`:

```
class DocumentHelper extends Controller
{
    protected $container;

    /** ************************************************************************
     * Constructor
     * @param type $container
     **************************************************************************/
    public function __construct($container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }


    /** ************************************************************************
     * Attach Document(s) to an $entity according to the information given in the
     * form.
     * @param Entity $entity
     * @param string $redirectRouteName Name of the route for the redirection after successfull atachment
     * @param string $redirectParameters Parameters for the redirect route
     * @return Response
     **************************************************************************/
    public function attachToEntity($entity, $redirectRouteName, $redirectParameters)
    {
        $folder = $entity->getFolder();
        if($folder == NULL){
            $folder = new Folder();
            $entity->setFolder($folder);
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(new FolderType(), $folder);

        // ------------- Request Management ------------------------------------
        $request = $this->get('request');
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
          $form->bind($request); // Link Request and Form

          if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($folder);
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($redirectRouteName, $redirectParameters));
          }
        }


        return $this->render('MyProjectMediaBundle:Folder:addDocument.html.twig', array(
            'form'      => $form->createView(),
            'entity'    => $entity,
        ));
    }
```

Doing that way, I just have to add one small action in each relevant controller, let say `EmployeeController.php`:

```
public function addDocumentAction(Employee $employee)
    {        
        $redirectRouteName = 'MyProjectCore_Employee_see';
        $redirectParameters = array('employee_id' => $employee->getId());
        return $this->get('myprojectmedia.documenthelper')->attachToEntity($employee,$redirectRouteName,$redirectParameters);
    }
```

Same principle for the display, in the helper I have the common function which I call in my already-existing `seeAction()` and in the TWIG file I import the common "Document list" display.

That's all folks!

I hope this can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Doctrine ORM, i think you're searching for the Mapped Superclasses inheritance.

The docs are better than words :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses

Comment: It's interresting thanks, I didn't know those Mapped Superclasses. However, It seems that it isn't possible to have a Many-To-Many (or even a One-To-Many) relation in a Mappedsuperclass. I'll continue investigation on these mappedsuperclasses to see if I can find a workaround ; if you have any advice, don't hesitate. In any case, it will be useful for other parts of my project :)