# One entity serving multiple other entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

#### Case

In my Symfony application I have the following entities:
- Customer
- Contact (ManyToMany with Customer)

I have also created a Note entity (with attachments, but that is a simple 1-N relation with Note) which I want to relate with Customer and Contact. But the question is, how?

#### Possible solution 1

Create a standard OneToMany relation between Customer/Note and Contact/Note.
The Note entity gets two columns: `customer_id` and `contact_id`.
This will certainly work fine, however, there's always one column with a `NULL` value. That feels like bad design.

#### Possible solution 2

ManyToMany or OneToMany with extra join table.
Each entity that can have Notes is creating a join table: customer_notes, contact_notes, etc.

Pros: All fields are filled with data
Cons: ManyToMany doesn't feel like the right solution: To get the customer related to the Note I have to use a `foreach` or `$customers[0]` because Doctrine returns an array of customers, which should only return one customer of course. The OneToMany with extra join isn't bidirectional, but I will come back on that later.

#### Possible solution 3

Mapped superclasses, like [Link 1 entity with many others kind of entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166795/link-1-entity-with-many-others-kind-of-entities)
I could create a superclass with the $notes property and extend the Customer or Contact entity with this superclass. But after reading the above linked question, I doubt if this is the best solution. The example in [Many-To-One with multiple target entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016444/many-to-one-with-multiple-target-entities) is 'easy': Fruit and Vegetable are both types of Food. But Customer and Contact don't have something in common, except that they both can have notes.

#### Note: Unidirectional or bidirectional?

The most important direction is Customer -> Notes. All the notes must be displayed on the `Customer/show.html.twig` page or `Contact/show.html.twig` page. The other direction would be nice for my breadcrumbs (see other note).

#### Note: URL construction

If I create routes like /customer/{customer_id}/note/{note_id} to display a note for a customer, I could retrieve a Customer object by using the URL paramater $customer_id. Therefore I don't need a bidirectional relation because I can retreive the customer by URL. However, for every entity I need to duplicate the code. It would be nice to have shareable code for CRUD operations on a Note which adapts to the entity the Note belongs to.

#### Summary

As you can see, a lot of possibilities for my question. I am relatively new to Symfony and I would like to solve it the 'professional' way and I hope to receive some guidelines about how to solve this question.

#### Edit:

- Notes can be created for every kind of entity that can have Notes (Customer, Contact, or for future purposes: Task, Employee, etc).
- Everything is in one Bundle (AppBundle)
- To be honest, the first focus is just to have Notes on Customer and Contact. I could solve it by creating solution #4:

#### Possible solution 4

Create a Note entity for every kind of Note (CustomerNote, ContactNote). That would be just a simple OneToMany relation. However, a lot of (almost) duplicate code, which possobily can be avoided with a solution I am looking for.

I am not against this solution, but it feels like there exists a better solution than this and I feel stupid when a CTRL-C and CTRL-V a lot of code ;)

Comment: Customer and Contact DO have something in common, they both have notes, i think the mappedSuperClass is the best way to go, or solution 1, i think its not bad design to have a null value for the not used column, i think thats pretty logically

Comment: will a note only be created on a contact instance?

Comment: How about two note entities? Do you manage your customers and contacts in the same bundle? After reading your question, I am wondering if one note entity per bundle could be a good idea.